# while(true)loop is forcing my app to crash in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement an infinite loop as i want the code to run the follwing code again and again...but it is causing my app to crash...as i am a beginner in this tech, i am not aware of this...any help will be appreciated..thank you..

Here is the Logcat

```
  06-20 22:04:38.029 22848-22848/sensor.swapni E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL 
  EXCEPTION: main
                                                           Process: 
   sensor.swapni, PID: 22848

   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 13571692 byte allocation 
   with 7716072 free bytes and 7MB until OOM
                                                               at 
   java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:118)
                                                               at 
   android.view.ViewRootImpl$RunQueue.postDelayed(ViewRootImpl.java:8656)
                                                               at 
   android.view.View.postDelayed(View.java:14275)
                                                               at 
   sensor.swapni.Second.onCreate(Second.java:54)
                                                               at 
   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
                                                               at 

android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
                                                               at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
                                                               at 
 android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
                                                               at   
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
                                                               at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
                                                               at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                               at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                               at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                                                               at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                               at
```

And here is the java code

```
 while(true) {
        tv1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tv1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }, 1000);
        tv1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tv2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                tv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }, 2000);
```

Comment: Can you post the error that you are getting please? @Alex

Comment: What are you trying to do here

Comment: That would be because your loop executes far faster than android can process all these tasks, so tasks fill up the queue and eventually this either fails with some kind of QueueOverflow exception, or your JVM will simply run out of memory.

Comment: @cunnniemm no error is shown...app is ruuning fine...but when the turn for this code comes...it crashes...

Comment: @Alex what is the point of this code? What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: @Derek i want 1st text to appear...now after 1 sec it should disappear and next 2nd text should be visible(and hiding 1st one simultaneously) and vice versa...and that also for infinite time

Comment: @cunnniemm i want 1st text to appear...now after 1 sec it should disappear and next 2nd text should be visible(and hiding 1st one simultaneously) and vice versa...and that also for infinite time

Comment: @Alex Post the stack trace... There is definitely a stack trace, otherwise the app wouldn't be crashing.

Comment: From what I can get from the code snippet is that multiple threads are being created as a result of the while loop. You could remove the while-loop and have the thread call itself on completion or use a JobScheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these two methods to your class:

```
private void setVisibility1() {
    tv1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    tv1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setVisibility2();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

private void setVisibility2() {
    tv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    tv2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    tv1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setVisibility1();
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

And replace the whole loop with one call to this method:

```
setVisibility1();
```

setVisibility1 switches the visibility and starts the timer for setVisibility2. When setVisibility2 is executed it changes the visibility again and starts the timer for setVisibility1.

Comment: error:method reference are not supported in -source 7.0...can u suggest me any other alternate for  tv1.postDelayed(this::setVisibility1, 1000);
} as it is showing error when i am trying to run the app using the method by this way...

Comment: @Alex edited for Java7. To be fair: IF you have access to the current visibility, Gabe Sechan's solutions is more clean.

Answer (score 5):

That loop will run thousands of times per second.  Each time it runs, it adds at least 4 objects to the heap (2 Runnables, 2 Messages to the handler).  Eventually you run out of memory.

If you want to continually do something every 2 seconds, you call postDelayed once on the actual thread, and inside the runnable you call it again.  Like this:

```
   tv1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tv1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tv1.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: exactly, in addition every 2 sec both textviews are set at the same time visible and invisible by the two Runnables (not a crush cause, but still something wrong imo, if you want to add in the explaination :) )

Comment: True.  He probably wants to have the first runnable post the second and the second post the first.

Comment: Now, I'm curious. Which one would happen first: the OutOfMemory exception or the ANR?

Comment: Or he can schedule the tasks so execution time of first is not dependent on executon time of second.

Comment: @GabrielCosta  Depends on the amount of memory in the device, the speed of the loop, and the timeout period of the ANR.  It would be a race condition between the watchdog timer and the growth of memory (since none of the memory would be collectable).  Assuming he's on a function that can ANR (very likely).

Comment: OR he can rewrite the two to become one that gets the visibility and toggles it.  Which is probably the best answer.

Comment: @GabeSechan not able to fix my problem...it's running but only for one time and i want it to run for infinite time...and when i try to run your code  inside while(true) it is still crashing..

Comment: @Alex that's why you repost. Put a breakpoint in the code I wrote and you'll see it is running repeatedly.  Then you need to rewrite it so the two runnables don't conflict.  Really you only need/want one runnable here.

Comment: @Alex this code runs repeatedly. The logic just isn't correct. You'll just need additional code to determine whether the 'tv' is visible or not. If it's visible, set it to invisible and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely an out of memory issue. Try to set a timer instead of creating tons of new Object.

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: I would opt for some `ScheduledExecutorService` myself.

Answer (score 0):

You Shouldn`t use it inside main thread specially when you are doing operation inside it. You may have to use some thing like that.

```
   viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        while (statues==true){
            if (statue==true){
                delay(500)
                   //ToDo


             }
        }
}
```